# WPF UserControl still active after Viewbox Child switch

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, user-controls

I have a viewbox and an initial child usercontrol that displays a webbrowser. If I open pandora or youtube and begin playing audio and the click a button to switch the viewbox child to a new user control, visually it changes but I can still hear the audio in the background.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Background music -- call it a feature!

Comment: haha thanks, but I already have that implemented :)

Answer (score 0):

The same behavior (audio playing for Pandora or YouTube) is true for tabbed browsers as well. The web site owners consider it a feature to continue playing the audio.

Since you cannot change their implementation, the only option you have is to dispose of the web control, or navigate to a different URL (say about:blank) to unload the web page (which will stop the audio).